# Passing arguments to lstinputlisting using pgfkeys

Tags: macros, listings, pgfkeys

I am writing a macro to put code and a figure side by side. There are three relevant files: `main.tex`, `figure.tex`, and `ch1.tex`.

`main.tex` is roughly this:

```latex
...
\usepackage{listings}
...
\lstdefinestyle{base}{
...
}
\lstdefinestyle{C}{
    style=base,
    language=C,
}
...
\input{figure}
...
\begin{document}
...
\include{ch1}
...
\end{document}
```

`figure.tex` defines my macro, and it has (among other things) this:

```latex
....
\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\def\figpath{./figs/}
\def\codepath{./code/}
\makeatletter
...
% set of keys and default values for group "fig"
\pgfkeys{/codefig/entities/.cd,
  code-file/.initial=DUMMY.txt,
  code-width/.initial=0.5,
  code-opts/.initial={style=Plain},
  fig-file/.initial=DUMMY,
  fig-page/.initial=1,
  fig-width/.initial=0.5,
  fig-inner-width/.initial=0.8,
  caption/.initial={},
  label/.initial={},
}

% practical "setter" and "getter" functions
\def\codefig@set@keys#1{\pgfkeys{/codefig/entities/.cd,#1}}
\def\codefig@get#1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/codefig/entities/#1}}

\newcommand\CodeFigure[1]{%%
\bgroup%%
\codefig@set@keys{#1}%%
\vspace{\figAir}
\begin{figure}[htbp]\centering%%
\begin{minipage}[b]{\codefig@get{code-width}\textwidth}
\lstinputlisting[\codefig@get{code-opts}]{\codepath\codefig@get{code-file}}
\centering (a)
\end{minipage}%%
\begin{minipage}[b]{\codefig@get{fig-width}\textwidth}
\centering\includegraphics%%
    [width=\codefig@get{fig-inner-width}\textwidth,page=\codefig@get{fig-page}]%%
    {\figpath\codefig@get{fig-file}}\\%%
\centering (b)
\end{minipage}%%
\caption{{\codefig@get{caption}}}%%
\label{\codefig@get{label}}%%
\end{figure}%%
\vspace{\figAir}
\egroup%%
}

\makeatother
```

Finally, `ch1.tex` intends to use this macro like this:

```latex
\CodeFigure{
  code-file={my-code.c},
  code-width=0.6,
  code-opts={style=C},
  fig-file=the-fig-filename,
  fig-page=2,
  fig-width=0.4,
  fig-inner-width=0.6,
  caption={Some Nice Caption},
  label={some-label},
} %% this is line 643
```

However, latex yells at me saying:

```
./ch1.tex:643: Package keyval Error: style=C undefined.
```

I am guessing that the "name=value" string is not being correctly parsed, but I don't know how to achieve that. If I change the line:

```
\lstinputlisting[\codefig@get{code-opts}]{\codepath\codefig@get{code-file}}
```

for this:

```
\lstinputlisting[style=C]{\codepath\codefig@get{code-file}}
```

it works as expected. However, hardcoding the options *'is not an option'* as I need to pass different ones in different parts of my document.

Comment: Please provide code we can test. But controlling expansion *might* help.

Comment: Try `\expandafter\lstinputlisting\expandafter[\codefig@get{code-opts}]{\codepath\codefig@get{code-file}}`...

Comment: @PaulGaborit a single `\expandafter` won't be enough, `\codefig@get` needs four steps of expansion...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expansion control is really the key here. You'll want to have `\lstinput` only see the value as you passed it in, not the entire `\codefig@get` thing (as the underlying `keyval` parser then doesn't see an equals sign or comma on which to split, and thinks the entire thing is a single key, during the error message typeout the thing will get expanded, hence you see `style=C` as an error).

The following defines another auxiliary called `\codefig@eget` that will fully expand the `\pgfkeysvalueof` using `\romannumeral`-expansion (so if a value would have a leading space that would be gobbled, and it continues to expand the value until it hits the first unexpandable token -- at least in your usage this shouldn't be a problem, if it turns out to be one you could rely on the `\pgfkeysvalueof` implementation to always need a known number of expansion steps, though this could change in the future and hence might be a bad idea), the auxiliary always needs exactly two steps to expand to the value, and protects its result from further expanding inside an `\expand` or `\edef` context.

I've removed the `\vspace`s you put around your `figure` environment, those are just wrong. The `figure` might float to another place, in which case you put two `\vspace` in the midst of your document leading to a weird looking unwanted space. If you want to control the spacing around your floats there are different means to that, search the site.

I also removed the group around the `figure` and instead moved the key-parsing inside it, as the `figure` forms a group of its own and you don't need the values outside of it.

The `\figpath` macro is also a bad idea, you could use the `\graphicspath` command of `graphics`/`graphicx` instead. I still left your `\figpath` in the code.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\def\figpath{}
\def\codepath{./}

\makeatletter
% set of keys and default values for group "fig"
\pgfkeys{/codefig/entities/.cd,
  code-file/.initial=DUMMY.txt,
  code-width/.initial=0.5,
  code-opts/.initial={style=Plain},
  fig-file/.initial=DUMMY,
  fig-page/.initial=1,
  fig-width/.initial=0.5,
  fig-inner-width/.initial=0.8,
  caption/.initial={},
  label/.initial={},
}

% practical "setter" and "getter" functions
\def\codefig@set@keys#1{\pgfkeys{/codefig/entities/.cd,#1}}
\def\codefig@get#1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/codefig/entities/#1}}
\def\codefig@eget#1%
  {%
    \unexpanded\expandafter
      {\romannumeral`\^^@\pgfkeysvalueof{/codefig/entities/#1}}%
  }

\newcommand\CodeFigure[1]
  {%
    \begin{figure}[htbp]%
      \codefig@set@keys{#1}%
      \centering
      \begin{minipage}[b]{\codefig@get{code-width}\textwidth}%
        \expanded{\noexpand\lstinputlisting[{\codefig@eget{code-opts}}]}%
          {\codepath\codefig@get{code-file}}
        \centering (a)
      \end{minipage}%
      \begin{minipage}[b]{\codefig@get{fig-width}\textwidth}%
        \centering
        \includegraphics
          [{width=\codefig@get{fig-inner-width}\textwidth,page=\codefig@get{fig-page}}]%
          {\figpath\codefig@get{fig-file}}\\
        (b)
      \end{minipage}%%
      \caption{\codefig@get{caption}\label{\codefig@get{label}}}%
    \end{figure}%%
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\CodeFigure{
  code-file={\jobname.tex},
  code-width=0.6,
  code-opts={language=[LaTeX]TeX,firstline=1,lastline=4},
  fig-file=example-image-duck,
  fig-page=2,
  fig-width=0.4,
  fig-inner-width=0.6,
  caption={Some Nice Caption},
  label={some-label},
}
\end{document}
```

---

Alternative approach: Don't use `pgfkeys` but `expkv-cs` (handy, because the individual keys can be directly accessed via `#1`...`#9` in `\ekvcSplit` and you don't have to care about expansion), and `expkv-def` (interface to define keys with predefined key types, similar to `pgfkeys` handler approach, though defining and setting are in separate commands).

Also, instead of prefixing all the keys with `fig-` or `code-` I simply defined two wrapper keys to set the options instead.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{expkv-cs,expkv-def}
\def\figpath{}
\def\codepath{./}

\makeatletter
\ekvcSplit\codefig@code
  {
     file  = DUMMY.txt
    ,width = .5
    ,opts  = style=Plain
  }
  {%
    \begin{minipage}[b]{#2\textwidth}%
      \lstinputlisting[{#3}]{\codepath#1}
      \centering (a)
    \end{minipage}%
  }
\ekvcSplit\codefig@fig
  {
     file  = DUMMY
    ,page  = 1
    ,width = .5
    ,inner-width = .8
  }
  {%
    \begin{minipage}[b]{#3\textwidth}%
      \centering
      \includegraphics
        [{width=#4\textwidth,page=#2}]%
        {\figpath#1}\\
      (b)
    \end{minipage}%%
  }

\ekvsetdef\codefig@set@keys{codefig@keys}
\ekvdefinekeys{codefig@keys}
  {%
     dataT label   = \codefig@label
    ,dataT caption = \codefig@caption
    ,data  code    = \codefig@codekeys
    ,data  fig     = \codefig@figkeys
  }
\newcommand\codefig@caption@aux[1]{\caption{#1\codefig@label\label}}

\newcommand\CodeFigure[1]
  {%
    \begin{figure}[htbp]%
      \centering
      \codefig@set@keys{#1}%
      \codefig@codekeys\codefig@code{\codefig@code{}}%
      \codefig@figkeys\codefig@fig{\codefig@fig{}}%
      \codefig@caption\codefig@caption@aux
    \end{figure}%%
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\CodeFigure{
  code = {
    file={\jobname.tex},
    width=0.6,
    opts={language=[LaTeX]TeX,firstline=1,lastline=4},
  },
  fig = {
    file=example-image-duck,
    page=2,
    width=0.4,
    inner-width=0.6,
  },
  caption={Some Nice Caption},
  label={some-label},
}
\end{document}
```

---

Result of both:

[image]

Comment: Wow, what a thorough explanation, it works perfectly on my computer.